# Convert Symbol to a String in Elisp

Tags: string, elisp, symbols

How can I convert a symbol type into a string in Emacs lisp?

I wasn't able to find a `symbol-to-string` function or anything similar.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Try using [`symbol-name`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html#index-symbol_002dname-487):

```
(symbol-name 'some-symbol)
```

Comment: And for the reverse, `(intern "some-string")`.

Answer (score 5):

Given a symbol name (a string), you can get the symbol's value.  Using Trey Jackson's solution:

```
(setq ASymbol 10)  => 10
(intern "ASymbol")  => 'ASymbol (e.g. the unevaluated symbol with name "ASymbol")
(symbol-value (intern "ASymbol")) => 10
```

This is useful if you want to get the values of symbols for which you only have names.  For instance, you read them from a string.

A few notes: `intern` returns the value of the symbol with the given name. If no symbol with such a name exists, it creates a symbol with that name. You can use `intern-soft` to avoid introducing a new symbol if one with the given name does not exists.